# Is this a SimpleDateFormat/Datetime bug?

Tags: datetime

Here is the `SimpleDateFormat` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for reference.

The `week in year` format does not seem to function correctly at year end. For example, if I try to format `2014-12-30` to get this information, I get a value of `1`. I would expect `52`.

```
Datetime example = Datetime.newInstanceGMT(
    Date.newInstance(2014, 12, 30),
    Time.newInstance(12, 0, 0, 0)
);
system.debug(example.format('w')); // "Week in year" - outputs 1
system.debug(example.format('W')); // "Week in month" - outputs 5
```

Since `week in month` should only ever be greater than `week in year` in this peculiar circumstance, it seems I can implement the following workaround:

```
public Integer getWeekInYear(Datetime toParse)
{
    Integer weekInYear = Integer.valueOf(toParse.format('w'));
    Integer weekInMonth = Integer.valueOf(toParse.format('W'));
    return (weekInMonth > weekInYear) ? 52 : weekInYear;
}
```

Is this a bug in either the `DateTime` type or `SimpleDateFormat`? Is the logic in `getWeekInYear` sound?

Comment: Practically speaking based on the calender dates, 2014-12-21 to 2014-12-27 is the 52nd week. 2014-12-30 and 2015-01-01 fall under the same week which is first week of the year. Please let me know if you think I'm wrong. :)

Comment: I do, in that case I would think 2014-12-30 falls under the 53rd week of 2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is nothing to do with Salesforce.

> As per [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) If 1 January is on a Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday or Thursday, it is in week 01. If 1 January is on a Friday, Saturday or Sunday, it is in week 52 or 53 of the previous year (there is no week 00). 28 December is always in the last week of its year. The ISO week-numbering year starts at the first day (Monday) of week 01 and ends at the Sunday before the new ISO year (hence without overlap or gap). It consists of 52 or 53 full weeks.

According this 1st week of 2015 is Dec 28, 2014- Jan 3, 2015. That's why you are getting week no as 1.

You can validate the week no here. http://www.timeanddate.com/date/weeknumber.html